# Set up a local wi-fi access point on computer

Tags: wifi, raspbian

I have not very powerful computer and I would like to use it as a local Web-Server which can be reached through the wi-fi access point. So I want my computer be a wi-fi access point.

The computer does not have a wi-fi, so I put wi-fi adapter in it. There are manuals about raising wi-fi access points, but everywhere this is used like a bridge to the internet. For instance, I put wi-fi adapter to my comp, then I connect comp and router through the Ethernet and after editting some configs I will have wireless access to the Internet.

This is not what I want to achieve. I need lokal wi-fi access point and then I am going to raise LAMP on this computer.

For getting my goal I configured dhcp-server, this is dhcp.conf:

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authority
subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.10.10 192.168.10.20;
 option broadcast-address 192.168.10.255;
 option routers 192.168.10.1;
 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200;
 option domain-name "local-network";
 option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

Then I tried to configured hostapd, this is /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
# Basic configuration

interface=wlan0
ssid=wifi
channel=1
#bridge=br0

# WPA and WPA2 configuration

macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=YourPassPhrase
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

# Hardware configuration

driver=rtl871xdrv
ieee80211n=1
hw_mode=g
device_name=RTL8192CU
manufacturer=Realtek
```

**I have different manufacturer and device name of my adapter**.. why so.. do I need to change it? 
I configured hostapd by running these commands:

```
wget https://github.com/jenssegers/RTL8188-hostapd/archive/v1.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf v1.1.tar.gz
cd RTL8188-hostapd-1.1/hostapd
sudo make
sudo make install
```

output of /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet static
   address 192.168.10.1
   netmask 255.255.255.0
```

After all of this I am expecting to have wi-fi point access named wifi with a password YourPassPhrase, according to /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf, but it is not about to happen.

So where is my mistake?

P.S.
OS - Raspbian

Comment: why post the text of everything except the interfaces file?  just post the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.  nobody wants to see an image of text.  [Please don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself and format it as code with the `{}` icon in the editor.

Comment: Yes, I just thought it is irrelevant.. but I have done as you said